# JLabel (component) as image - how do i get the file name of the image?

Tags: java, components, jlabel

I was wondering how can i get the File name of the image in a JLabel?
-note- i only have the JLabel nothing else
What i've tried:

```
public static String get(Component c){
    String s = c.getName();
    retrun s;
}
```

But my problem is it returns null.

Comment: I have to wonder if this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  Do you really need the original file?  You already have an [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html), which you can paint into a BufferedImage, which you can then do with as you please, including writing it to a new file if necessary.

Comment: never mind the question i have figured a way out my self but thanks!